# Cannot get Content-Security-Policy to work

Tags: security

I'm trying to implement CSP, but cannot make the `script-src` work correctly. I strongly want to avoid `unsafe-inline`, but all attempts to circumvent this by using sha256 hashes seem to fail.

This is what happens: Several `<a>`tags on the page are being modified by javascript after loading (the modifying javascript is an external file from `self`and is accepted and correctly executed). This javascript does the following to such an `<a>` tag:

```
MyAElement.href="javascript:void(0);";
MyAElement.onclick=function(){showpart(this);}
MyAElement.onfocus=function(){showpart(this);}
```

(where `showpart` is defined in the aforementioend external javascript file).
When I click on such a modified link, I get a CSP violation report.
What confuses me slightly is that even if I temporarily use `Content-Securtity-Policy:` and not just `Content-Securtity-Policy-Report-Only:`, the website seems to function alright. I conclude that it is in fact the `javascript:void(0);` that triggers the error.

It should be possible to get rid of the error by supplying a suitable hash.
I tried both

```
#echo -n "javascript:void(0);" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | base64
```

and

```
#echo -n "void(0);" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | base64
```

but without success (i.e. even with `script-src` containing

```
'sha256-kbHtQyYDQKz4SWMQ8OHVol3EC0t3tHEJFPCSwNG9NxQ=' 
'sha256-Deekn20h+++EarpL0nFQLX7JSJv7s/2W9f988ZFAh14='
```

) the message still occurs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, `javascript:` hrefs are not supported by csp hashes or nonces. I don't think they will ever be supported either. I used to actively participate in the w3c webappsec where csp and hashes were defined and I seem to recall this coming up and the group simply saying that `javascript:` hrefs need to go away. I could also be misremembering with a bias to my own feelings towards that pattern :)

If you want to avoid the violation, I think you could bind the click event and prevent propagation of the event.

Comment: So if I interprete that correctly, I should not set `href` at all, change the signature of `showpart` to `showpart(this, event)` and in it do `event. stopPropagation()`?